# synonymes de l'expression "par exemple" dans une dissertation

Tags: vocabulaire, synonymes

I'm writing an essay in French, and whilst in English there are loads of synonyms for the phrase 'for example,' I'm struggling to find a similar phrase in French. I have used 'Notamment' in my essay countless times as well, so that's not a great option.
Is there any other phrases for 'par exemple,' to introduce another idea into your essay? Or is the vocab slightly limited here and I'm just going to have to accept repeating myself over and over again?

Comment: There are more available than *notamment*. Have you tried looking for synonyms in a thesaurus (e.g. [here](https://dictionnaire.orthodidacte.com/article/synonyme-par-exemple) or [here](https://www.dictionnaire-synonyme.com/synonyme-par-exemple)?

Comment: Perhaps "à titre d'illustration" (for illustrative purposes) or "pour illustrer mon propos" ( to illustrate my point). Other option : "en particulier" (especially).

Comment: What synonyms would you use in English? It's probably easier to start from them.

Answer (score 2):

Certaines expressions existent qui mettent en valeur une particularité de l'exemplification ; évidemment, ce n'est pas souvent le cas qu'il y ait une particularité valant la peine d'être mentionnée et peu de ces expressions conviennent comme remplacement  de « par exemple » (« à titre d'exemple », « en guise d'exemple »). Néanmoins le mot « exemple » reste textuellement irremplaçable dans les expressions listées ci-dessous et dans beaucoup d'autres.

**Les exemples abondent de… prenons celui de** (*On peut donner beaucoup d'exemples.*)

- Les exemples abondent de personnes à des postes importants qui ont dû rendre des comptes à la justice, prenons celui du dernier ministre de la justice.

**à titre d'exemple** (*Ce qui suit n'est mentionné que comme exemple.*)

- À titre d'exemple on peut parler de la guerre d'Irak.

**pour ne citer qu'un exemple** (*Il y en a beaucoup, mais on n'en cite qu'un. https://fr.hinative.com/questions/534805*)

- Pour ne citer qu'un exemple, le problème de la page 14 possède ces caractéristiques.

**en prenant pour exemple** (*On montre quelque chose à partir de l'exemple choisit.*)

- En prenant pour exemple la Guerre du Golfe, qui a coûté environ 40 milliards de dollars, soit un milliard par jour de guerre, on pourrait estimer un soldat à 1 ' équivalent de 100'000 dollars.  ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Un_t%C3%A9moin_du_XXe_si%C3%A8cle_La_conqu%C3%AAte_d/70dwAAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22pour+exemple%22&dq=%22pour+exemple%22&printsec=frontcover))

**prenons pour exemple** (*Un exemple semble habituel dans ce cas.*)

- Prenons pour exemple les doctrines de Hegel . Au lieu de montrer leurs défauts , qui ne manquent pas , on dit : C'est un homme que personne ne comprend , et ses disciples même les plus ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Dictionnaire_des_missions_catholiques_pa/ZiMAAAAAQAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22pour+exemple%22&pg=PA43&printsec=frontcover))

**il n'y a que peu d'exemples, dont**

- Il n'y a que peu d'exemples dont celui de la liberté de la presse.

**en guise d'exemple** (*Le cas cité possède à peu près les caractéristiques de ce que l'on appelle un exemple*)

- En guise d'exemple, nous pourrions citer le personnel de la restauration qui aura connaissance de certains PAI si des régimes alimentaires sont prescrits pour cause d'allergie alimentaire. ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Concours_Infirmier_de_l_%C3%A9ducation_natio/k76ZEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22en+guise+d%27exemple%22&pg=PA15&printsec=frontcover))

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord pour dire que le mot « exemple »  est irremplaçable. En plus de *notamment*  (le seul figurant dans la question, et pourtant de nombreuses listes de synonymes sont très facilement accessibles) personnellement j'utilise souvent *tel que* et *entre autres*.

Comment: @None On peut dans certains cas se passer de « par exemple » et se servir de « tel que » et « entre autres », ou « parmi lesquels/lesquelles », mais il est nécessaire de changer la structure de la phrase ; il ne peut pas s'agir d'un remplacement tel qu'en anglais lorsqu'on remplace « example » par « instance ». C'est le cas pour les expressions que je liste dans ma réponse ; néanmoins je peux ajouter cette précision.

Answer (score 1):

- Comme
- En particulier
- Je citerais
- Disons